How to mount a Mac host folder on a QEMU guest Linux?
I recompiled the Debian kernel enabling the required options in QEMU/9psetup installed QEMU (8.2.1) with Homebrew and started it as follows:
/usr/local/bin/qemu-system-x86_64 \
    -M accel=hvf \
    --cpu host \
    -hda /Users/lucas/.debian/debian.img \
    -m 8G \
    -smp 4 \
    -nographic \
    -net nic \
    -net user,hostfwd=tcp::3000-:3000,hostfwd=tcp::2222-:22 \
    -virtfs local,path="$HOME",mount_tag=host0,security_model=passthrough,id=host0 \

However, when mounting host0 with the command below, the folder can only be accessed with the root user and in read-only mode.
mount -t 9p -o trans=virtio,version=9p2000.L host0 /mnt/


@Giacomo1968 It didn't work with just the rw option nor with all options (rw, username, uid, gid, file_mode, dir_mode)

To use p9 with security_model=passthrough, it's necessary to start QEMU as a superuser. If you want to use it as a regular user, you need to switch to security_model=mapped-xattr.
/usr/local/bin/qemu-system-x86_64 \
        -M accel=hvf \
        --cpu host \
        -hda /Users/user/.debian/debian.img \
        -m 8G \
        -smp 4 \
        -nographic \
        -net nic \
        -net user,hostfwd=tcp::3000-:3000,hostfwd=tcp::2222-:22 \
        -virtfs local,path=$HOME,mount_tag=share,security_model=mapped-xattr,id=share,fmode=0644,dmode=0755`

Additionally, you need to use bindfs to translate macOS and Linux metadata as shown at https://github.com/utmapp/UTM/discussions/4458#discussioncomment-3818945
sudo bindfs --map=501/1000:@20/@1000 /mnt/macOS /home/user/macOS 

However, in the fstab of that link, when bindfs is executed before the mount completes, the partition is not mounted. To fix this, it's necessary to add the option x-systemd.automount (https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/490282/421376).
share   /mnt/macos  9p  trans=virtio,version=9p2000.L,rw,_netdev,nofail     0   0
/mnt/macos    /home/user/macOS    fuse.bindfs map=501/1000:@20/@1000,nonempty,x-systemd.requires=/mnt/macos,x-systemd.automount   0 0

